# Getting hashcode address instead of an array list

Tags: arraylist

Another simple Java issue from a simple, and brand new, Java user. I need to print an array list of months both by name and by month number. What I am getting is the has address results instead.

I have attempted to create an Arrays.toString but cannot seem to work it out.

Here is the code.

```java
//Author

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MonthApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Month<Integer>> monthsByNumber = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<Month<String>> monthsByName = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] monthNames = { "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "Novemeber", "December" };
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
            monthsByNumber.add(new Month<Integer>(i));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < monthNames.length; j++) {
            monthsByName.add(new Month<String>(monthNames[j]));
        }

        System.out.println(monthsByName);
        System.out.println(monthsByNumber);

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm a dummy. I figured it out. I just needed to add:
@Override 
     public String toString() {
      return month.toString();
 }
to the month.java file, which I had not included here.